# How to only show nested attributes within parent model's method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, nested

I gamefied forming good habits with my web app.

Calling `<%= habit.current_level %>` shows the current level you are at on your habit.

This will list all `date_missed` for a habit, but how can we edit this to only show `date_missed` for the `current_level`?

**habits/_habit**

```
  <% habit.levels.each do |level| %>
    <% level.missed_dates.each do |missed_dates| %>
      <% if missed_dates.date_missed.present? %>
          <%= missed_dates.date_missed %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

`current_level` comes from **habit.rb**

```
def current_level
        return 0 unless date_started
      def committed_wdays
        committed.map do |day|    
          Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES.index(day.titleize)
        end
      end

      def n_days
        ((date_started.to_date)..Date.yesterday).count do |date| 
          committed_wdays.include? date.wday
        end - self.real_missed_days
      end     

  case n_days     
      when 0..9
        1
      when 10..24
        2
      when 25..44
        3
      when 45..69
        4
      when 70..99
        5
      else
        6
    end
end
```

Habits `has_many` Levels, which `has_many` MissedDates

**MissedDatesController**

```
  def create
    habit = Habit.find(params[:habit_id])
    habit.missed_days = habit.missed_days + 1
    habit.save!
    level = habit.levels.find(params[:level_id])
    level.missed_days = level.missed_days + 1
    if level.missed_days == 3
      level.missed_days = 0
      level.days_lost += habit.calculate_days_lost + 2
    end
    level.save!
    head :ok # this returns an empty response with a 200 success status code
    @missed_date = level.missed_dates.new(missed_date_params)
    @missed_date.save
  end
```

### UPDATE

```
def current_level
  return 0 unless date_started

  def committed_wdays
    committed.map do |day|
      Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES.index(day.titleize)
    end
  end

  def n_days
    ((date_started.to_date)..Date.yesterday).count do |date|
      committed_wdays.include? date.wday
    end - self.real_missed_days
  end

  case n_days
    when 0..9
      1
    when 10..24
      2
    when 25..44
      3
    when 45..69
      4
    when 70..99
      5
    else
      6
  end
end

def real_missed_days
  value = 0
  levels.each do |level|
    value += level.missed_days + level.days_lost
  end
  value
end

def calculate_days_lost
  def n_days
    ((date_started.to_date)..Date.yesterday).count do |date|
      committed_wdays.include? date.wday
    end - self.real_missed_days
  end

  case n_days
    when 0..9
      n_days
    when 10..24
      n_days-10
    when 25..44
      n_days-25
    when 45..69
      n_days-45
    when 70..99
      n_days-70
    else
      n_days-100
  end
end

def days_left_in_current_level
  def n_days
    ((date_started.to_date)..Date.yesterday).count do |date|
      committed_wdays.include? date.wday
    end - self.real_missed_days
  end

  case n_days
    when 0..9
      10-n_days
    when 10..24
      25-n_days
    when 25..44
      45-n_days
    when 45..69
      70-n_days
    when 70..99
      100-n_days
    else
      0 # No end
  end
end

def progress_in_percent
  calculate_days_lost / (calculate_days_lost + days_left_in_current_level).to_f * 100
end
```

Comment: In the current_level method, you return an integer (case n_days ...), what do you mean by this integer? I mean, what is this integer in the level model? can you past level.rb?

Comment: level.rb is just `belongs_to :habit`  @SoufyaneBouchaala. The integer represents number of days since `date_started`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating though all `levels` just pass the `current_level` directly into the inner block:

```
<% habit.current_level.missed_dates.each do |missed_dates| %>
  <% if missed_dates.date_missed.present? %>
    <%= missed_dates.date_missed %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: For some reason that gives me `undefined method 'missed_dates' for 1:Fixnum` I've tried other variations with the same result. Thanks for your help again!

Comment: Seems like your `current_level` method returns a number and not a `level` object. Btw your `current_level` method in the question looks strange (there is no `end` to that method).

Comment: I think the `end` is there. I updated the rest of the model so you can see. If I add an end anywhere else then I get an error so I'm pretty sure it's there. Yea `current_level` returns a number. Does that mean I have to duplicate the habit.rb `current_level` code into days_missed.rb?

Comment: Hmm, you define method in other methods - that confuses me. But isn't `current_level` the same than `levels.last`?

Comment: All the levels are built from creation. `current_level` figures out what level the habit is on at the moment.

Comment: Is there a way to apply the `current_level` method in the parent to the child's child model?